# Increasing the efficiency of a python code by using arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, matplotlib, plot

I have the following python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class bifurcation_diagram(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.omega = []
        self.theta = []
        self.dt = (2 * np.pi / (2.0 / 3.0)) / 600
        self.time = []
        self.theta_in_bifurcation_diagram = []
        self.F_D = np.arange(1.35,1.5,0.001)
        self.theta_versus_F_D = []
    def calculate(self):
        l = 9.8
        g = 9.8
        q = 0.5
        Omega_D = 2.0 / 3.0
        for f_d in self.F_D:
            self.omega.append([0])
            self.theta.append([0.2])
            self.time.append([0])
            for i in range(600000):
                k1_theta = self.dt * self.omega[-1][-1]
                k1_omega = self.dt * ((-g / l) * np.sin(self.theta[-1][-1]) - q * self.omega[-1][-1] + f_d * np.sin(Omega_D * self.time[-1][-1]))
                k2_theta = self.dt * (self.omega[-1][-1] + 0.5 * k1_omega)
                k2_omega = self.dt * ((-g / l) * np.sin(self.theta[-1][-1] + 0.5 * k1_theta) - q * (self.omega[-1][-1] + 0.5 * k1_omega) + f_d * np.sin(Omega_D * (self.time[-1][-1] + 0.5 * self.dt)))
                k3_theta = self.dt * (self.omega[-1][-1] + 0.5 * k2_omega)
                k3_omega = self.dt * ((-g / l) * np.sin(self.theta[-1][-1] + 0.5 * k2_theta) - q * (self.omega[-1][-1] + 0.5 * k2_omega) + f_d * np.sin(Omega_D * (self.time[-1][-1] + 0.5 * self.dt)))
                k4_theta = self.dt * (self.omega[-1][-1] + k3_omega)
                k4_omega = self.dt * ((-g / l) * np.sin(self.theta[-1][-1] + k3_theta) - q * (self.omega[-1][-1] + k3_omega) + f_d * np.sin(Omega_D * (self.time[-1][-1] + self.dt)))
                temp_theta = self.theta[-1][-1] + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta + 2 * k2_theta + 2 * k3_theta + k4_theta)
                temp_omega = self.omega[-1][-1] + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_omega + 2 * k2_omega + 2 * k3_omega + k4_omega)
                while temp_theta > np.pi:
                    temp_theta -= 2 * np.pi
                while temp_theta < -np.pi:
                    temp_theta += 2 * np.pi
                self.omega[-1].append(temp_omega)
                self.theta[-1].append(temp_theta)
                self.time[-1].append(self.dt * i)
            for i in range(500,1000):
                n = i * 600
                self.theta_in_bifurcation_diagram.append(self.theta[-1][n])
                self.theta_versus_F_D.append(f_d)
    def show_results(self):
        plt.plot(self.theta_versus_F_D,self.theta_in_bifurcation_diagram,'.')
        plt.title('Bifurcation diagram' + '\n' + r'$\theta$ versus $F_D$')
        plt.xlabel(r'$F_D$')
        plt.ylabel(r'$\theta$ (radians)')
        plt.xlim(1.35,1.5)
        plt.ylim(1,3)
        plt.show()

        
bifurcation = bifurcation_diagram()
bifurcation.calculate()
bifurcation.show_results()
```

I wish to make it more compact and make a coloured plot, along with increasing its efficiency. Any help in this regard would be truly beneficial.

I was expecting the code to run fast but it takes more than fifteen minutes to run.

Comment: Your inner loop runs 600 million times.  Perhaps your expectations were unreasonable.  You CAN replace your two `temp_theta` loops with modulo operations, but that's a relatively small improvement.

Comment: You can get a slight improvement by building `omega`, `theta` and `time` in locals, and then appending them to the `self` versions after the loop.

Comment: You could use list comprehensions instead of for loops to create new lists. This can save time and space by avoiding the need to call append () on every iteration. Maybe [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/10-ways-to-speed-up-your-python-code-e3d57630b710) could help?

Comment: strongly recommend 1) preallocate all lists as a numpy arrays 2) using `numba` package for this. I am pretty sure this code could be vectorized, but it should be much easier to switch to numba. You can optimize it down to seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is not made for such a code because it is generally **interpreted** using CPython (it is meant to be done for glue codes and scripts) and CPython performs (nearly) no optimizations of the code so repeated expressions are recomputed. The usual way to speed up such a code is to use **Numpy** functions operating on large arrays (not lists). THis is called **vectorization**. That being said, this code is pretty expensive and using Numpy may not be enough and it is also a non-negligible work to use Numpy here. An alternative solution is to use **Numba** so to compile this code (thanks to a JIT compiler). Note that Numba is meant to speed-up codes using mostly Numpy and basic numerical computations (not general-purpose codes like plotting).

The first thing to do is to get ride of lists and replace them by Numpy arrays. Arrays can be preallocated at the right size so to avoid the expensive  calls to `append`. Then, the computing function should be moved away from the class so for Numba to be easily used. Then, the two `while` loops can be replaced by `np.remainder`. Finally, you can compute each row of the arrays in **parallel** using multiple threads.

Here is the resulting code (barely tested):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64)', parallel=True)
def compute_numba(F_D, dt):
    l = 9.8
    g = 9.8
    q = 0.5
    Omega_D = 2.0 / 3.0
    size = 600000
    loop2_start, loop2_end = 500, 1000
    loop2_stride = 600
    omega = np.empty((F_D.size, size+1), dtype=np.float64)
    theta = np.empty((F_D.size, size+1), dtype=np.float64)
    time = np.empty((F_D.size, size+1), dtype=np.float64)
    theta_in_bifurcation_diagram = np.empty((loop2_end-loop2_start) * F_D.size, dtype=np.float64)
    theta_versus_F_D = np.empty((loop2_end-loop2_start) * F_D.size, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in nb.prange(F_D.size):
        f_d = F_D[i]
        omega[i, 0] = 0.0
        theta[i, 0] = 0.2
        time[i, 0] = 0.0
        for j in range(size):
            cur_omega = omega[i,j]
            cur_theta = theta[i,j]
            cur_time = time[i,j]
            tmp = np.sin(Omega_D * (cur_time + 0.5 * dt))
            k1_theta = dt * cur_omega
            k1_omega = dt * ((-g / l) * np.sin(cur_theta) - q * cur_omega + f_d * np.sin(Omega_D * cur_time))
            k2_theta = dt * (cur_omega + 0.5 * k1_omega)
            k2_omega = dt * ((-g / l) * np.sin(cur_theta + 0.5 * k1_theta) - q * (cur_omega + 0.5 * k1_omega) + f_d * tmp)
            k3_theta = dt * (cur_omega + 0.5 * k2_omega)
            k3_omega = dt * ((-g / l) * np.sin(cur_theta + 0.5 * k2_theta) - q * (cur_omega + 0.5 * k2_omega) + f_d * tmp)
            k4_theta = dt * (cur_omega + k3_omega)
            k4_omega = dt * ((-g / l) * np.sin(cur_theta + k3_theta) - q * (cur_omega + k3_omega) + f_d * np.sin(Omega_D * (cur_time + dt)))
            temp_theta = cur_theta + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta + 2 * k2_theta + 2 * k3_theta + k4_theta)
            temp_omega = cur_omega + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_omega + 2 * k2_omega + 2 * k3_omega + k4_omega)
            temp_theta = np.remainder(temp_theta + np.pi, 2 * np.pi) - np.pi
            omega[i,j+1] = temp_omega
            theta[i,j+1] = temp_theta
            time[i,j+1] = dt * j
        for k, j in enumerate(range(loop2_start, loop2_end)):
            n = j * loop2_stride
            offset = (loop2_end - loop2_start) * i + k
            theta_in_bifurcation_diagram[offset] = theta[i,n]
            theta_versus_F_D[offset] = f_d
    return (omega, theta, time, theta_in_bifurcation_diagram, theta_versus_F_D)

class bifurcation_diagram(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.omega = np.array([])
        self.theta = np.array([])
        self.dt = (2 * np.pi / (2.0 / 3.0)) / 600
        self.time = np.array([])
        self.theta_in_bifurcation_diagram = np.array([])
        self.F_D = np.arange(1.35,1.5,0.001)
        self.theta_versus_F_D = np.array([])
    def calculate(self):
        self.omega, self.theta, self.time, self.theta_in_bifurcation_diagram, self.theta_versus_F_D = compute_numba(self.F_D, self.dt)
    def show_results(self):
        plt.plot(self.theta_versus_F_D,self.theta_in_bifurcation_diagram,'.')
        plt.title('Bifurcation diagram' + '\n' + r'$\theta$ versus $F_D$')
        plt.xlabel(r'$F_D$')
        plt.ylabel(r'$\theta$ (radians)')
        plt.xlim(1.35,1.5)
        plt.ylim(1,3)
        plt.show()

        
bifurcation = bifurcation_diagram()
bifurcation.calculate()
bifurcation.show_results()
```

On my i5-9600KF processor with 6 cores, this code takes 1.07 secondes rather than about 19 min 20 for the initial one! As a result, this new code is about **1150 times faster**!

Besides, I also find the resulting code easier to read.

I advise you to check the results, although they look fine at first glance.
Indeed, here is the resulting graph I got so far:

[image]