# How to speed up this code for Poincare Section using Numba?

Tags: python, performance, numba, processing-efficiency, runge-kutta

I have the following Python code for constructing a Poincare Section for chaotic Pendulum which uses RK4 algorithm and np arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

# Define function to calculate equations
def f(t, Yvec):
    """
    Computes the vector f.
    """
    theta = Yvec[0]
    omega = Yvec[1]
    phi = Yvec[2]
    fvec = np.zeros(3)
    fvec[0] = omega
    fvec[1] = -g/l*np.sin(theta) - gamma*omega + A*np.sin(phi)
    fvec[2] = drive
    return fvec

# Define a function for RK4 method
def rk4(t, Y_n, h):
    """
    Computes the vector Y(t_{n+1}).
    """
    k1 = h*f(t, Y_n)
    k2 = h*f(t + h/2, Y_n + k1/2)
    k3 = h*f(t + h/2, Y_n + k2/2)
    k4 = h*f(t + h, Y_n + k3)
    Y_nplus1 = Y_n + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6
    return Y_nplus1

# main program

# Define constants
g = 9.8  # acceleration due to gravity
l = 9.8  # length of the pendulum
gamma = 0.2  # damping coefficient
A = 1.2  # amplitude of driving force
drive = 2/3   # angular frequency of driving force
n = 2  # order of ODE

# Define time interval and step size
dt = 0.001  # step size
t0 = 0  # initial t
tf = 100000  # final t
t = np.arange(t0, tf, dt)

# Initialize array filled with zeroes to store solution after every increment
theta_array = np.zeros(len(t))
omega_array = np.zeros(len(t))
phi_array = np.zeros(len(t))

# Define Y vector with initial conditions which are also the values for first element of the arrays
Y = [0, 0, 2*np.pi] 
theta_array[0] = Y[0]
omega_array[0] = Y[1]
phi_array[0] = Y[2]


# Increment the Y vector according to RK4 and keep storing values in the arrays by defining a loop
sols = []
for i in range(len(t) - 1):
    Y_new = rk4(t[i], Y, dt)
    theta_array[i+1] = Y_new[0]
    omega_array[i+1] = Y_new[1]
    phi_array[i+1] = Y_new[2]
    # Check for Poincare section
    if np.abs(Y_new[2] % (2*np.pi)) < dt:
        sols.append([np.mod(Y_new[0] + np.pi, 2*np.pi) - np.pi, Y_new[1]])
    Y = Y_new
    
sols = np.array(sols)

# Define the color map
cmap = cm.get_cmap('plasma')

# Plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
for i in range(len(sols)):
    color = cmap(i / len(sols))
    ax.plot(sols[i,0], sols[i,1], '.', markersize=2, color=color)

ax.set_xlabel('θ')
ax.set_ylabel('ω')
plt.show()
```

Right now it takes more that 30 minutes to run this code. I tried decreasing the step size but then I don't get a clear Poincare Section. How to speed up the compilation of this code using Numba?

Comment: Take the sine and any other scalar function from `math`. Or import directly from `libm`. The third component is useless, using `phi=drive*t` has the same result. With the careful management of current boundaries it is possible to replace the modular reduction with two comparisons. // Can you report what difficulties you had when enabling numba.jit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Numba is pretty simple here : you can use add the decorator `@nb.njit` to the two first function and convert `Y` to an array using `np.array`. This is definitively something you could have simply tried, especially after [your previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891739/increasing-the-efficiency-of-a-python-code-by-using-arrays). Once done, I get a 6x speed-up which is already good but not great.

The main bottleneck then is the huge number of Numba function calls and the calls to `np.abs` (Numpy is designed to be fast when operating on large arrays, not scalars). You can put the main loop in a Numba function so to get a better speed up. I get a speed up of 30x on my machine (1 min 41 instead of > 50 min).

The Numba code is still taking a lot of time allocating array of size 3 which is not efficient. If you want a faster code, you can preallocate all the array and then use loops to avoid creating any (additional) temporary arrays. I think this should be twice faster.

Here is the final code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

# Define function to calculate equations
@nb.njit
def f(t, Yvec):
    """
    Computes the vector f.
    """
    theta = Yvec[0]
    omega = Yvec[1]
    phi = Yvec[2]
    fvec = np.zeros(3)
    fvec[0] = omega
    fvec[1] = -g/l*np.sin(theta) - gamma*omega + A*np.sin(phi)
    fvec[2] = drive
    return fvec

# Define a function for RK4 method
@nb.njit
def rk4(t, Y_n, h):
    """
    Computes the vector Y(t_{n+1}).
    """
    k1 = h*f(t, Y_n)
    k2 = h*f(t + h/2, Y_n + k1/2)
    k3 = h*f(t + h/2, Y_n + k2/2)
    k4 = h*f(t + h, Y_n + k3)
    Y_nplus1 = Y_n + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6
    return Y_nplus1

@nb.njit
def compute(theta_array, omega_array, phi_array, t, Y, dt):
    sols = []
    for i in range(len(t) - 1):
        Y_new = rk4(t[i], Y, dt)
        theta_array[i+1] = Y_new[0]
        omega_array[i+1] = Y_new[1]
        phi_array[i+1] = Y_new[2]
        # Check for Poincare section
        if np.abs(Y_new[2] % (2*np.pi)) < dt:
            sols.append([np.mod(Y_new[0] + np.pi, 2*np.pi) - np.pi, Y_new[1]])
        Y = Y_new
        
    sols = np.array(sols)
    return sols

# main program

# Define constants
g = 9.8  # acceleration due to gravity
l = 9.8  # length of the pendulum
gamma = 0.2  # damping coefficient
A = 1.2  # amplitude of driving force
drive = 2/3   # angular frequency of driving force
n = 2  # order of ODE

# Define time interval and step size
dt = 0.001  # step size
t0 = 0  # initial t
tf = 100000  # final t
t = np.arange(t0, tf, dt)

# Initialize array filled with zeroes to store solution after every increment
theta_array = np.zeros(len(t))
omega_array = np.zeros(len(t))
phi_array = np.zeros(len(t))

# Define Y vector with initial conditions which are also the values for first element of the arrays
Y = np.array([0, 0, 2*np.pi] )
theta_array[0] = Y[0]
omega_array[0] = Y[1]
phi_array[0] = Y[2]


# Increment the Y vector according to RK4 and keep storing values in the arrays by defining a loop
sols = compute(theta_array, omega_array, phi_array, t, Y, dt)

# Define the color map
cmap = cm.get_cmap('plasma')

# Plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
for i in range(len(sols)):
    color = cmap(i / len(sols))
    ax.plot(sols[i,0], sols[i,1], '.', markersize=2, color=color)

ax.set_xlabel('θ')
ax.set_ylabel('ω')
plt.show()
```

Here is the beautiful result:

[image]